Access token for Microsoft Teams Device Management API
I would like to programmatically manage Teams Devices. E.g. run a script like this that manages configuration profiles. The way to run this is catch the access token from the browser's dev tools. Since it is possible to programmatically get access tokens for the Teams Powershell module without any UI interaction, I figured the same should be possible for device management. As a first try, I followed Microsoft's instructions to get the token, just swapping out the scope for the required one (https://devicemgmt.teams.microsoft.com/.default). While that does get me a token, any operation I run against https://admin.devicemgmt.teams.microsoft.com/api/v2 results in
{"error":"Error in validating the roles of the user with tenantId: <my tenant id>, userId: da354b6a-0862-4710-bc0f-bf27e6ccc8cc:MSAL Get Token Exception :- DeviceManagement.Exceptions.MsalAcquireTokenException"}

I then tried giving the app registration access to the 'Teams Devices Administrator role', granted application_access permission, added TeamWorkDevice.ReadWrite.All MS Graph permission (not expecting anything from that one since I'm not requesting an MS graph token.. but you never know). All that resulted in no change. I have no idea what that user with id da354.. is.
Looking at how things are done in the browser, the token for that scope is fetched for client_id 2ddfbe71-ed12-4123-b99b-d5fc8a062a79 (I'm assuming that's the Id of the TAC), grant_type refresh_token and a refresh token is provided. Unfortunately, no refresh_token is returned when fetching the access token for TeamsPowershell.
Has anybody managed to tackle this?
For reference, this is the content of my POST
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1

client_id=<id_of_my_app_registration>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fdevicemgmt.teams.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=<secret of my app registration>&grant_type=client_credentials

Here's how I perform the logins (which work to get a token for the teams management API (scope = 48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default) and ms graph):
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "client_id", id_of_my_app_registration },
    { "scope", "48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default" },//this is a contstant value
    { "client_secret", secret_of_my_app_registration }
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }
};

var uri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{config.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
using var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
// now get the token from contentString

For my id_of_my_app_registration when it has the right permissions, I get the token and can use it. Likewise for MS graph (just replace the scope with https://graph.microsoft.com/.default). For the scope https://devicemgmt.teams.microsoft.com/.default, I do get the token, but I cannot use it and I'm getting the error mentioned above.

The error you're encountering might suggest that the user (or app) does not have the necessary permissions. The userId in the error indicates that it may be checking for user roles. Ensure you are using the app token properly, and not confusing user-based authentication with app-based authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token


If you look at the content of my POST request, you'll see it's a client_credentials grant type, thus tied to an app registration (identified by client_id) and its secret. This works fine to get a token for MS graph, as well as the teams management API. There's no user involved anywhere (a token for a user would be a grant_type = password). I do suspect that behind the scenes a token for devicemanagement.teams.microsoft.com does some magic, using some built-in user to internally get a token - unfortunately, nothing is documented so I'm left guessing

Just updated my question with the codw how I fetch the tokens. As you can see, there's no MSAL Library being used, so the DeviceManagement.Exceptions.MsalAcquireTokenException that's something internal, and there's no user anywhere. It seems running operations on the Teams device management API internally fetches another token and uses some built-in user to do so (the user having id da354b6a-0862-4710-bc0f-bf27e6ccc8cc). Since that's all internal, nothing I can do about it and the error doesn't tell me which permission is missing either.

we will check and let you know the updates,
